# What can we make out of the final scene from House of Cards season 1 ep 2?

Tags: plot-explanation, house-of-cards

At season 1, ep 2, Frank Underwood walks out of his office after successfully sabotaging the would-be secretary of state and installing Durant as the new secretary of state, Frank walks into a homeless man being restrained by police officers.

Frank walks towards this homeless man and tells him something like "Do not scream, no one cares and no one will hear you, why do you not let those good officers take you home." This homeless man calms down and Frank walks away.

What is the point of this scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is no need to read too much into it. The scene has about the same meaning as the opening scene where Francis kills a dog - to define Frank's character, the way he treats other beings.

Answer (score 2):

To me, this scene highlights Frank's:

- extreme political pragmatism, the often true belief that "having power" beats "being morally right"
- ruthlessness, as he shows absolutely no compassion for a homeless man in distress

  This is particularly interesting to me because most people including me would also ignore such a homeless man, but not be so brutally honest about the situation just to feel good about themselves in an act of hypocrisy.

The exact transcript for better Google SEO:

> Officer: Some guy was trying to get into the building, when we said "no" he started tearing his clothes off.
>
> Frank to homeless man: Nobody can hear you. Nobody cares about you. Nothing will come of this. Why don't you let these nice gentlemen take you home?